# Third party libraries shows error in wrong language

Tags: android

If third paty libraries have several translation (google play), they show error messages on german. I have translation files for english, franch, russian, but error are still in german.
How can request to look for requiered locals if present or use english as default?
[image]

Comment: what is the locale on your tablet? Maybe German is the default language for this library (if there is an English translation).

Comment: my default local - English.  Thats why, I am so surprised with German.  Google play is translated on huge number of locals, so it is not en issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error was cause by manual change of local. 
new Locale("default") does not exists and cause unexpectied local settings.